# How to reconnect to socket after disconnecting in html5

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, websocket

I'm working with HTML5 socket functions to establish a socket connection to my server. HTML5 has functions below to handle disconnecting

```
Socket.onclose = function()
{
...
}
Socket.onerror = function()
{
...
}
```

My problem is, how try for reconnect after onclose function executes? I tried to put a while loop inside of it like

```
ws.onclose = function()
{
  While(conn==0)
  {
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://example.com");
  }
}
```

and

```
ws.onopen = function()
{
conn=1;
...
}
```

But did't work.

Any idea?

Comment: I recommend you look this project: https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script that comes with the [Plezi websocket framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi)... It's fairly basic, but it works on the browsers I used it on (Safari, Chrome and FireFox).

The trick is to leverage the `onclose` method WITHOUT a loop.

**The `onclose` method will be called even if the websocket never opened and the connection couldn't be established** (without calling `onopen`).

Initiating a reconnect within an `onclose` is enough.

Writing a loop or a conditional review will not only fail, but will halt all the scripts on the page. Allow me to explain:

- Javascript is **single threaded**. Again: it's an even/task based, *single threaded*, environment.

  This means that your code acts like an *atomic* unit - nothing happens and nothing changes until your code finished running it's course.
- Because connections could take a while to establish, the `new WebSocket` was designed (and rightfully so) as an asynchronous function.

  This is how come you can define the `onopen` event callback AFTER the creation of the event.
- **The new websocket connection will be attempted only once the current task/event is finished**...

  ...so a loop will get you stuck forever waiting for a task that ***can't*** be performed until your code stops running...

Back to the issue at hand, here's the code. If you have any ideas for improvements, please let me know:

```
// Your websocket URI should be an absolute path. The following sets the base URI.
// remember to update to the specific controller's path to your websocket URI.
var ws_controller_path = window.location.pathname; // change to '/controller/path'
var ws_uri = (window.location.protocol.match(/https/) ? 'wss' : 'ws') + '://' + window.document.location.host + ws_controller_path
// websocket variable.
var websocket = NaN
// count failed attempts
var websocket_fail_count = 0
// to limit failed reconnection attempts, set this to a number.
var websocket_fail_limit = NaN
// to offer more or less space between reconnection attempts, set this interval in miliseconds.
var websocket_reconnect_interval = 250

function init_websocket()
{
    if(websocket && websocket.readyState == 1) return true; // console.log('no need to renew socket connection');
    websocket = new WebSocket(ws_uri);
    websocket.onopen = function(e) {
        // reset the count.
        websocket_fail_count = 0
        // what do you want to do now?
    };

    websocket.onclose = function(e) {
        // If the websocket repeatedly you probably want to reopen the websocket if it closes
        if(!isNaN(websocket_fail_limit) && websocket_fail_count >= websocket_fail_limit) {
            // What to do if we can't reconnect so many times?
            return
        };
        // you probably want to reopen the websocket if it closes.
        if(isNaN(websocket_fail_limit) || (websocket_fail_count <= websocket_fail_limit) ) {
            // update the count
            websocket_fail_count += 1;
            // try to reconect
            setTimeout( init_websocket, websocket_reconnect_interval);
        };
    };
    websocket.onerror = function(e) {
        // update the count.
        websocket_fail_count += 1
        // what do you want to do now?
    };
    websocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        // what do you want to do now?
        console.log(e.data);
        // to use JSON, use:
        // var msg = JSON.parse(e.data); // remember to use JSON also in your Plezi controller.
    };
}
// setup the websocket connection once the page is done loading
window.addEventListener("load", init_websocket, false);
```